# $2$ stations and $1$ job, different exponential rates, find total service time

Tags: probability, expectation, exponential-distribution

> A job is processed with $\lambda \sim \mu_1$ at Station 1
>
> Station 2 processes the jobs at $\mu_2$ but it has a $0.5$ probability
>   of sending the job back to Station 1 (regardless of the # of times
>   it's been processed).
>
> What is the expected waiting time?

I found the probability of the job being processed $n$ times to be $0.5^n$

Thus the expected service time $\mathbb E[S]$

$$=\sum_1^\infty (1/\mu_1 + 1/\mu_2 )n\times0.5^n$$

Is this correct?

If so, I tried to do it using another method:

Suppose I complete the first 2 stations in $1/\mu_1 + 1/\mu_2$ .Then I have $0.5$ probability to go back to where I started, and the expected time is the same again. Thus:

$$\mathbb E[S]=(1/\mu_1 + 1/\mu_2 + \mathbb E[S])\times 0.5$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time in service is $S$. Denote the time it takes to be processed once by station $1$ and once by station $2$ as $B$. This means that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[B] = \frac{1}{\mu_1} + \frac{1}{\mu_2}.
\end{equation}

The probability that a job is processed $n$ times by station $1$ and $2$ is indeed $0.5^n$. So,

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[S] = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n \mathbb{E}[B] 0.5^n = \mathbb{E}[B] \frac{0.5}{(1 - 0.5)^2} = 2 \mathbb{E}[B].
\end{equation}

The other approach is almost correct. $\mathbb{E}[S]$ is at least $\mathbb{E}[B]$ and with probability $0.5$ you need to start over. So,

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}[B] + 0.5 \mathbb{E}[S] \quad \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[S] = 2 \mathbb{E}[B].
\end{equation}